# What is the "/" notation in this Turing Machine State Transition table?

Tags: turing-machines

Looking at this page: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-machine/#SomeSimpExam

In Table 4 there is a / used in two places: when in state q1 and you read a 0, for example. What does that symbol mean?

[image: Here is the table]

Comment: They appear to be transitions that never occur, so it doesn't matter what the entry is. (E.g., the machine is assumed to start while scanning a $1$, so $q_1$ is never entered while scanning $0$.)

Comment: Thank you very much!